# Laptop with LG reflective LCD?

Tags: laptop, lcd

Six or seven months ago LG demoed a reflective or backlit (switchable) LCD display (I found a news article [here](http://gizmodo.com/5115471/lg-transmissivereflective-lcd-will-work-just-as-well-outdoors-as-in)).  Are there any laptops on sale using this display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reply from LG customer support:

> Dear Customer,
>
> Thank you for contacting LG
>   Electronics concerning your
>   computer-related inquiry.
>   Unfortunately we don't support laptops
>   in the U.S. as of yet and we're not
>   sure where and if we are. You can call
>   our sales office at 201-816-2242 and
>   they should be able to assist you.
>
> If you have other questions or
>   concerns, please do not hesitate to
>   contact us again either via email, or
>   by calling our customer service
>   division at 800-243-0000 at your
>   convenience.
>
> E-mail Administrator Customer
>   Interactive Center

So it looks like I'm out of luck.  I will give the number a call tomorrow to see what their take is on it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done as much searching as I think I can do and I have not seen any word on this outside of all the stories that broke around CES 2009. I think all you could possibly do is email someone at LG and see if they could provide you any information concerning it.

Comment: Not a bad idea, emailed their cust. serivce and will update if they get back to me.

Comment: Hope it works out for you. I would be interested to know any information myself.